# How to pass application arguments to the spring boot app using -Dloader.main

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a spring boot application and I'm using the below command to start my app. I have a custom classpath to set while running the app, that's why I'm using the below approach.

```
java -classpath target/app.jar;<my_classpath_here> -Dloader.main=<my_spring_boot_app_class_here> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

I want to pass application arguments to my app. How can I do it ? I have tried `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments` , but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass arguments by using the below

```
java -classpath target/app.jar;<my_classpath_here> -Dloader.main=<my_spring_boot_app_class_here> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher my_arg=value
```

NOTE : I was initially passing the argument, before the JarLauncher parameter and hence it wasn't working. I moved the argument to next to JarLauncher and it worked.